# C: fopen(); is producing unhandled exception error

Tags: c, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, fopen

```
if ((fp = fopen(argv[2], "r")) == NULL){
    printf("Failed to load file");
}
```

I'm pretty new to C, I'm not sure why this is producing an error. It's opening a new window and saying

```
unhandled exception error.
```

What does this error mean? I am using Visual Studio 2013

Complete program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#pragma warning (disable:4996);

FILE * fopen(char *filename,char *access);


int main(int argc, char argv[]){

    FILE *fp = NULL;
    char fileContents[100] = { 0 };


    if ((fp = fopen(argv[2], "r")) == NULL){
        printf("Failed to load file");
    }

}
```

Comment: change to `if ((fp = fopen(argv[2], "r")) == NULL){`

Comment: this code is bad but doesn't generate any exceptions.

Comment: I thought C didn't have exceptions?

Comment: not those kind of exceptions. think of a float-point exception or SIGSEGV.

Comment: @BhargavRao: That's it! Thanks. I'm sorta embarrassed that I missed that :p.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing `char argv[]` to `char *argv[]`